# 動的変数と静的変数の概念

Tags: php

phpにおける動的変数と静的変数の概念は、C言語についての[知恵袋の回答](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13117262228)の

> 値を格納する領域を動的変数では動的に確保し、静的変数では静的に確保する…のですが、これでは何のことかさっぱり判りませんね。
>
> 静的変数はプログラム実行開始時にメモリのどこかに変数の領域を確保し、そのプログラムが終了するまでその領域を使い続けます。
>
> 例えば、関数hogeの中で静的変数sを定義したとします。そして関数hogeを呼び出して、静的変数sに何かしらの値を代入し、そこからリターンしても静的変数sの領域は確保されたままです。
>
> このため、次に関数hogeを呼び出したときに静的変数sが保持している値は前回関数hogeからリターンしたときの静的変数sの値をそのまま保持しています。そしてプログラムが終了すると、静的変数sの領域は破棄されます。
>
> なお、この静的変数sの値を関数hoge以外からも参照できるというわけではありませんので、誤解なきよう（ポインターを使って間接的に参照するのであれば別ですが）。
>
> 動的変数は関数が呼び出されたときにメモリ上のどこかに領域が確保され、関数からリターンするとその領域は破棄されます。やはり関数hogeの中で動的変数dを定義したとします。この動的変数dの領域は関数hogeが呼び出されるまではメモリ上のどこにも存在しません。
>
> 関数hogeが呼び出されると動的変数dの領域が確保され、何かしらの値を代入できるようになります。そして関数hogeからリターンすると、この動的変数dの領域は破棄されます。
>
> このため、関数hogeが呼び出されるたびに動的変数dはメモリ上の違う領域（同じ領域である可能性もありますが、同じ領域が使われる保証はありません）が使用されます。
>
> 以上の事が関数の動作にどのように関わってくるかですが、関数が内部情報を保持せず、また同時に複数の場所から呼び出されないなら、静的変数でも動的変数でも同じです。
>
> しかし、関数が内部情報を保持するためには静的変数を使用しなければなりません。例えば、ある関数が何回呼び出されたかを数えて、１０回呼び出されるごとに特別な処理を行いたいとします。
>
> この場合、呼び出された回数は静的変数に保持しなければなりません。動的変数だと関数からリターンするたびに変数の値は破棄されてしまいますから。

と同じようなものなのでしょうか。

Comment: 「動的変数」という言葉遣い自体あまり聞かれないと思いますし、PHPでこの言葉が使われている例を私は知りません。どちらでこの使い方をお聞きになりましたか？　あるいは、もしかすると[可変変数](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.variables.variable.php)のことでしょうか。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。申し訳ありません。参考としてリンクしてる質問サイトにおいて、とくに言語の指定がないまま質問されており、それに詳細な回答が返ってきていたので、所持しているPHPに関する書籍に静的変数に関する記述があるし、てっきり動的変数も書籍等の記述がないだけで存在している、或いは別の名前で呼ばれているのだろう、という推測で質問しました。※本当お恥ずかしい話ですが、よくよく見てみるとタグ付けに「知恵袋トップ>コンピュータテクノロジー>プログラミング>C言語関連」とあったようです。質問当時は、このタグ付けを見逃しておりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「静的変数 (static variables)」についての説明は、ご提示のものが C 言語でも PHP でも概ね正しいです。

ただし細かいことを言うと、「静的変数」という言葉には 2 つの意味があります。

1. 静的な記憶域期間 (static storage duration) を持つ変数
2. `static` 指定子がついた変数

前者の意味で「静的変数」と言うのであれば、グローバル変数は常に静的変数であり、C 言語でも PHP でもご提示の文章は正しいです。しかし PHP の[このマニュアル](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)で使われている「静的変数」については

> 静的変数はローカル関数スコープのみに 存在します

と書かれているため、グローバル変数を含んでおらず、どちらかというと後者の使い方です。後者の意味の場合、ご提示の文章は部分的に正しくないです。ここでは英語版 Wikipedia の ["Static variable" についての記事](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)が前者の意味で書かれていたので前者が一般的な用法であると判断しました。

---

「動的変数 (dynamic variables)」については議論が必要です。この単語は、少なくとも [PHP のマニュアル](http://php.net/manual/en/) には載っていません。PHP は C 言語と違って [GC](http://php.net/manual/ja/features.gc.php) のある動的型付けプログラミング言語ですので、スタック及びヒープの使い方が C 言語と異なります（この点については、ブログ記事[「メモリとスタックとヒープとプログラミング言語」](http://keens.github.io/blog/2017/04/30/memoritosutakkutohi_puto/)が参考になります）。したがってどのような変数を「動的変数」と呼ぶべきなのか、私は知りません。

また C 言語においても、「動的変数」という言葉は曖昧だと **私は** 思います。類似概念である[「自動変数 (automatic variables)」](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)には仕様レベルの定義があり、こちらの方がよく使われているように私は思います。ただし、周りの友人に聞いてみたところ「動的変数」を使っている方々もいらっしゃるようなので、この限りではありません。

<sup>**補足**: 今回の「動的変数」とは別に、Common Lisp には「動的変数 (dynamic variables)」ないし「スペシャル変数 (special variables)」という言葉が存在します。これは lexical scope / dynamic scope を区別するための言い方です。詳しくは [M. Hiroi さんの解説](http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/xyzzy_lisp/abclisp10.html)や、"Practical Common Lisp" の[第 6 章](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html)が参考になります。</sup>

Answer (score 0):

おおむね、その知恵袋の回答で合っていると思います。

PHPだとグローバル変数とstatic変数が静的変数で、その他は動的変数になると思います。
↑こちらコメントにご指摘により以下のように修正します。
動的変数は静的変数とグローバル変数を除いたものではないでしょうか。

http://php.net/manual/ja/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: 「静的変数」は "static variable" の和訳なので、この場合は「static変数」が何のことを指しているのかの説明がないとトートロジーに思えます。また、ご提示のマニュアルには「静的変数はローカル関数スコープのみに 存在します」と書かれていますが、naga3 さんのおっしゃる「静的変数」はグローバル変数も含むようなので、マニュアルと齟齬があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。調べたところ静的変数にグローバル変数は含まないのが通例みたいです。すみませんでした。static変数の説明は、おおむね知恵袋の回答で間違いないと思います。動的変数は、静的変数とグローバル変数を除いた変数ではないでしょうか。

Comment: static variable の対義語として "dynamic variable" を造りたくなるお気持ちは分かるのですが、たとえば一般的な static variable についての [Wikipedia 記事](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)によると static variable に対する概念は automatic variable だと書かれています。また `"動的変数" site:php.net` で検索しても何もヒットしません。そこで質問者さんにどこでこの言葉をお聞きになったのか[質問している](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42364/%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A8%E9%9D%99%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E6%A6%82%E5%BF%B5/42376?noredirect=1#comment43451_42364)次第です。（実は Common Lisp には別に "dynamic variable" という言葉があるので、微妙です。）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。PHPにおいて関数が処理を終えても情報を保持し続ける静的変数も存在するし、処理を終えると消えるやつも存在するけれども、それは"動的変数"とは呼ばない、というところでしょうか。間違っておったら申し訳ありません。

Comment: C言語ではスタックに格納する動的変数、ヒープに格納する静的変数という名称をよく使っていたのでそのイメージで回答しました。PHPでは確かに動的変数という名称は聞いたことがないです。